# Get the current value of a label's text value

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I did search other similar questions, most of which had to do with jscript.  I am having a difficult enough time trying to learn C#, so hopefully there is answer.  I seems like I always get close to the answer only to find I have hit another hidden exception.  What I am attempting to do is a work around for what must exist a more elegant way, but here it is:  I have a check box, that when checked, changes Label1 text to "1" and unchecked changes Label1 text to "0".  When the button on the page is clicked it sends data fields to a stored procedure.  Even though I can see that the label value is either 1 or 0, the send to SP function always sends 'NULL' for Label1, which I assume is the default value for a blank label.  So how do I get page to read the current value of the label when the button is clicked?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD/ XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<script runat="server">

public void InsertCard (object source, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}

public void CheckBox1_CheckChanged (object source, EventArgs e)
{  

    Response.Write("");  
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true) 
{  
        Label1.Text = "1";  
}  
    else
    {  
        Label1.Text = "0";    
    }  
}  

</script>  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
    <title></title>  
</head>  

<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
          <asp:sqldatasource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DevTestConnectionString %>"
    insertcommand="AddMember" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      <insertparameters>
        <asp:FormParameter Name="CardNumber" formfield="CardNumberBox" Type="int32" />
        <asp:FormParameter Name="NameFirst" formfield="NameBox" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter Name="Valid" formfield="Label1" Type="string" />
      </insertparameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>

        <div>  
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
            <hr />
            Last Name:<asp:TextBox id="NameBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br>              
            Card Number:<asp:textbox id="CardNumberBox" runat="server" />
            <br>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text=" Valid" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />  
            <br>  

       <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Add Card"     onclick="InsertCard" />
 </div> 
        </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I think that you would want to change the code and put it into the `CheckBox1_CheckStateChanged` event also `Button Clicks` trigger what is know as `PostBacks` so you could handle this several different ways, `JavaScript, HiddenField, Session Variable....etc` also I would move the Event Code out of the `<script>` tags why not just double click on the Button in the designer to auto generate the Click event.. then you would also what to do some `IsPostBack` conditional checking as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why used the label? Use the checkbox directly and set the datatype on the table column to bit.  Replace the label  to the below.

```
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox1" Name="Valid"   PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean"/>
```

Comment: I owe you a beer.  I was over thinking this problem way to much.  Thanks so much.